# Wifi Mesh My Only Other Option?

Tags: networking, wireless-router

I got a new router from my isp and it does not allow me to have a guest network.... It seems to be newer than my tp-link archer C80 so I would like to keep using it rather than putting it in bridge mode and running wifi from the tp link.

I really do need a guest network though as I do have airbnb in my **basement** and I do not want those guests to be on the same network as I am.

Right now I  have an ethernet cable from my isp router into my tp-link and then run a "guest" network from there.

It seems to work (really thought I would need to my isp one in bridge mode).

The isp router I get better speeds throughout the house but still can get as low as 50Mbps in the basement what would be enough for most guests.

The tplink one can give me as low as 10mbps in the basement which is crazy slow as my isp speed is 300mbps.

It would be nice to move the tp-link router down to the basement but it would be tons of work to run a ethernet cable to there and if do bridge mode then I lose wifi capability from my tplink.

So is doing a mesh really the only other way?

Comment: I think I would start at a way to put Ethernet into your basement. I did this with a conduit in a corner of a main floor closet that takes a formed RJ45 Plug. If you can do this, it gives you much flexibility in your other options.

Comment: `Right now I have an ethernet cable from my isp router into my tp-link and then run a "guest" network from there.` that's how I'd do it - a mesh won't help much if you suffer such low speeds with this setup ... i.e. a mesh doesn't magically penetrate walls/floors better than what you have

Comment: @John - Yeah I don't really have the no how to run a cable through to the downstairs so would take a while to figure that out plus probably would take quiet a bit of time to acheive...alot more than I have between guests and nothing I want to shut down over.

Comment: @Bravo - yeah the mesh still have to go through the walls and I will lose speed but at certian spots of the basement I am almost getting full speed so a mesh could eliminate some dead spots what are causing the slow down.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I stupidly didn't consider mesh WITHIN the basement :p Silly me

Answer (score -1):

I can do what you're asking on my ASUS router. If your main router tri-band or quad-band, you can break off the extra band and put it in its own network. In the ASUS documentation, it tells you how to set this up.

Alternately you can use 2 different routers. Run an ethernet cable from LAN port of the main router to the WAN port on the guest router.
If the 2nd router has a repeater function (like a travel router) then you can give a new network to guest routers (no cables needed). Travel routers from [GL-iNet](https://www.gl-inet.com/products/gl-sft1200/) can do this for example, there not expensive.